# SQL select data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select from multiples tables(10+) that are in the following format using mySQL.

```
+----------table(n)-----------+
+-----------------------------+
| url       | id        | ... |
+-----------+-----------+-----+
| url1.com  | 12345678  | ... |
| url2.com  | 45832458  | ... |
```

What I need to do is retrieve the id from each table for a given URL and return it in a single row like so.

```
+--------------table(n)--------------+
+------------------------------------+
| url       | table(n)  | table(n+1) |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| url1.com  | 12345678  | 8182735    |
```

But the URL might not exist for a given table, so I just need to retrieve all the ids from the tables where the URL is found.

For example, I have 10 tables and a URL/id is in 4 of them. I need to retrieve these 4, in a single row. I've tried to use aliases for columns along with various JOIN combinations to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're going to have a tough time of it with a variable number of columns in the output.  Can yo do it so you know how many columns you want ahead of time?

Comment: the number of tables is fixed, the number of results is not

Comment: Right, **the number of columns in the result**, is that fixed or not?

Comment: the number of columns in the result is variable depending on how many results for a url are found

Comment: See my answer.  This is tougher than it seems like it should be  with just SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `union all` and `group by`:

```
select url,
       max(id1) as id1, max(id2) as id2, . . .
from ((select url, id as id1, NULL as id2, . . .  from table1) union all
      (select url, NULL as id1, id as id2, . . .  from table1) union all
      . . .
     ) t
group by url;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I need to be able to specify a WHERE clause for a given URL(WHERE url='somepage.com'), how can I do that? do I need a WHERE clause for every table?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
SELECT tu.URL,COALESCE(table_1.id,0) AS table_1,COALESCE(table_2.id,0) As   
table_2,......,COALESCE(table_n.id,0) AS table_n  FROM Table_URL tu 
LEFT JOIN  table_1 ON tu.URL = table_1.URL
LEFT JOIN  table_2 ON tu.URL = table_2.URL
.
.
LEFT JOIN table_n ON tu.URL = table_n.URL
```

Comment: What about a variable number of columns?

Comment: @mikeb in that case your ans in this post is very help full.

Answer (score 0):

You want a variable number of columns generated by your SQL statement, and you cannot do that with MySQL.

You can see some techniques to get around it here:  [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Many reporting tools will let you do things like you want to, but using some sort of prepared statement hack with MySQL would be the only way to do it:

http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html