# Special connection between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I created 3 mysql tables:

table 'city': contains cities

```
i.e   |  name  |
      +========+
      | Athens |
      +--------+
      | Rome   |
      +--------+
      | Paris  |
      +--------+
```

table 'category': contains categories

```
i.e   |    name    |
      +============+
      | category_1 |
      +------------+
      | category_2 |
      +------------+
```

table 'shops': contains shops

```
i.e   |  name  |  category_name  |  city_name  |
      +========+=================+=============+
      | shop_1 |   category_2    |    Rome     |
      +--------+-----------------+-------------|
      | shop_2 |   category_2    |    Rome     |
      +--------+-----------------+-------------+
      | shop_3 |   category_1    |    Paris    |
      +--------+-----------------+-------------+
```

I'm trying to create a single query that will allow me to create the following html array(that shows how many shops there are in each city grouped by category):

```
|        ||   category_1   |  category_2 |
+========++================+=============+
| Athens ||        0       |      0      |
+--------++----------------+-------------|
| Rome   ||        0       |      2      |
+--------++----------------+-------------+
| Paris  ||        1       |      0      |
+--------++----------------+-------------+
```

Thank you in advance,
Giannis

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL dynamic pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773045/mysql-dynamic-pivot-table)

Comment: If the number of categories isn't fixed then you need to use dynamic sql. The question flagged as duplicate shows you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select c.name,
sum(case when s.category_name='category_1' then 1 else 0 end) as categoty_1,
sum(case when s.category_name='category_2' then 1 else 0 end) as categoty_2
from city as c left join shops as s on c.name=s,city_name
group by c.name
```

Comment: Thank you very much Madhivanan, it worked. Just a little correction: change "s,city_name" with "s.city_name"

Answer (score 0):

Look into this
    [SQL select data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248980/sql-select-data-from-multiple-)  tables/32249225?noredirect=1#comment52417831_32249225

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it wasn't what i exactly wanted. Madhinavan gave me the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select Name, isnull([category_1],0), isnull([category_2],0) from
(
    select city.name as Name, category.name as Category, count(category.name) as   [Count]
    from city left join shops on shops.city_name = city.name
    left join category on category.name =  shops.category_name
    group by  city.name, category.name
) as PivotSource
pivot 
(
    sum([Count]) for Category in ([category_1], [category_2])
) as PivotTable
```

Comment: Hi Amey, thanks for your time. I try your query too but it didn't run. Mysql returns error #1064